How to output PDF string to a smaller portion of the page (or iframe)?
I'm using Spatie Browsershot to create PDF files. Sometimes I don't need to actually save the PDF but just display it in the browser.
I can use the following method to display the PDF in the entire page:
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = Browsershot::html('<h1>Test</h1>')
        ->pdf();
    return response($pdf, 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
}

However I want to display the PDF in a smaller window inside the page, or a modal (or an iframe).
How can I do that?
The $pdfcontains a string that looks like that:
b"
%PDF-1.4
%ËÙÚß
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m126)
/CreationDate (D:20240716080820+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20240716080820+00'00')>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>

.. some long string..

/Root 15 0 R
/Info 1 0 R>>
startxref
12499
%%EOF

Is there a way to output this PDF inside smaller element?
The following didn't work:
// controller
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = Browsershot::html('<h1>Test</h1>')
        ->pdf();
    return view('index', ['pdf' => $pdf]);
}

And then in the view:
<iframe src="{{$pdf}}"></iframe>


Anything not working if you call the index controller from the first snippet as the src for the iframe?

<iframe src="{{$pdf}}"> - this would require a URI as value for the src attribute, but that is probably not what your view returned. You'd need to either make this into a Data URI, or use the srcdoc attribute instead. But it would probably be much easier, if you made the request that you are using to trigger this controller method, target an already existing iframe.

@cbroe thank you, can you please explain the last part of targeting an existing iframe?

You give the iframe a name, and then you use that name in the target attribute of a link or form, that you are using to go to your route that delivers this preview.

Thank you. It's similar to the below answer right?

<iframe src="{{ route('your.pdf.route.name') }}"></iframe>

and in your controller serving that route:
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $pdf = Browsershot::html('<h1>Test</h1>')
        ->pdf();
    return response($pdf, 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
}

